# Override a read-only property with a read-only Column that gets the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

A game engine provides me with a `Player` class that has an `uniqueid` read-only property to identify players. I would like to "convert" this into an SQLAlchemy's `Column` so that I can query players with it like this:

```
query = session.query(Player).filter(Player.uniqueid=='STEAM_0:0:1234567')
player = query.one_or_none()
if player is None:
    player = Player(uniqueid='STEAM_0:0:1234567')
```

Here's what my class currently looks like:

```
class Player(game.Player, db.Model):
    _uniqueid = Column('uniqueid', String(21), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, index, **kwargs):
        game.Player.__init__(index)  # initializes uniqueid
        db.Model.__init__(_uniqueid=self.uniqueid, **kwargs)
```

Next I would like to create a read-only interface for the `_uniqueid`, so the API users can no longer write to the variable (well, they can through `_uniqueid`, but that's on their responsibility since accessing it should happen through the non-private `uniqueid`).

I think of overriding the original `uniqueid` with a new one:

```
@property
def uniqueid(self):
    return self._uniqueid
```

This is read-only and "hides" the original `_uniqueid`, preventing anyone from writing to it unless they intentionally access the private one (I won't even list it in documentation, I'll only expose the non-private one).

The only problem is that this *completely* overrides the old one, meaning that my `__init__`'s `_uniqueid=self.uniqueid` won't work due to `self.uniqueid` using the *new* getter, not the old one.

So summed up, what I want is to convert a read-only property into a read-only something that can be used to query with SQLAlchemy. Is this possible, and if, how?

Comment: This most likely depends on how `game.Player.uniqueid` is implemented. What does it put in the instance dictionary? How do you set the value when you need to re-hydrate a `Player` instance from the database? Because this can be difficult to reason about for third party libraries, I generally don't recommend mixing model classes and third party classes like this.

Comment: @univerio It's just a read-only `property` which uses some C magic. Basically when a `player_join` event happens, the game engine provides with the `index` of the joining player, and doing `player = game.Player(index)` gives me an object which now has the `uniqueid` property readable from it.

Comment: But where is the actual data for `uniqueid` stored? You're saying it's computed from `index`? And all you need to rehydrate a `Player` is its index?

Comment: @univerio It's stored on Valve's servers I believe. I have no access to the game engine's source code (which is C++), all I'm given is a player's index, which is used as the sole parameter to a `Player` class, which constructs a player object that has an `uniqueid` property. The rest happens on the Source engine and Valve's servers.

Comment: But surely it's stored somewhere in memory if you can access it? The concern is, if it's stored somewhere in the instance dictionary, what is its name? Is it stored as `game.Player._uniqueid`, perhaps, in which case you'll need to be careful to not shadow it with your own attribute. Regardless, you can probably just do `super().__getattribute__("uniqueid")` to invoke the parent class's property.

Comment: @univerio It's not in the `__dict__` as it comes from the C side, similar to how a `list`'s values are not actually found with `dir()` since they're just stored on the C side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `super` to access the property of `game.Player`. We can test using a simple C extension type created with Cython:

```
# game.pyx
cdef class Player:
    cdef int index;

    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index

    @property
    def uniqueid(self):
        return "foo"


# test.py
class Player(game.Player, Base):
    __tablename__ = "player"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    _uniqueid = Column('uniqueid', String(21), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, index, **kwargs):
        game.Player.__init__(self, index)  # initializes uniqueid
        Base.__init__(self, _uniqueid=super().uniqueid, **kwargs)

    @property
    def uniqueid(self):
        return self._uniqueid

print(Player(1).uniqueid)  # "foo"
```

Because of the precariousness of inheriting from C extension types, this may or may not work depending on exactly what C magic the `game.Player` type uses.

Also, because the ORM bypasses `__init__` when it loads instances from the database, you'll have to hook into the [`load`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.load) event in order to initialize the `game.Player` type.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I completely forgot this question... Accepted and upvoted now, this indeed *does* work.